# Load Images from database [MS SQL Server]

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on a project - content listing app.

I would like to know what widget/ component I should use to load images from database and the resources/ references [websites] that I can refer to?

[App layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFjYF.jpg)
I wish to have such a layout as shown as above.

Comment: Asking for resources is not considered good on SO. Still, you can refer to http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/ for downloading images showing them in a list.

Comment: Also, for showing circular images you can use a library like this https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: Sir, I had found that tutorial before. It shows the listing in linear and I need it to be block by block, like the image I post. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks of your circular images info.

Comment: Do you mean a grid view? like this?  http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android Mind you, this example doesn't do SQL DB, but you'd get the UI part of it at least (it won't be efficient without a lot of work/3rd party library)

Comment: Is there any library that works you efficient? [you used before]

Comment: Sorry, the project we were working on required no external libraries (was for making a course assignment, and I was only helping the intern work on it) So I'm not too familiar with a suitable Library, but as long as the categories are 'static' and not too many of them, then you shouldn't have too many problems

Comment: The categories are dynamic as those categories would be added through backend website [CMS]. It could be many categories in the future. So, I need it to be loaded from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to pull image from a webserver and display then a grid view.

Downloading from the webserver isn't difficult and can be done in a lot of different ways, plus might depend on the rest of your code (But you should make sure to use some type of background threading, to prevent ANR)

Here is a likely better guide on how to setup a grid view. 
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

as @Anoop Kanyan stated This library looks to be very good for the circle images: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: Thanks. The answer seems helpful.